# Data usage API subscriber Id

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the `NetworkStatsManager` to get data usage info. However I can't understand the paramter subscriberId of the method `querySummaryForDevice`. What is it? Name of carrier? Phone number or what?

Reference [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html#querySummaryForDevice%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with [`TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSubscriberId()) for example.

> Returns the unique subscriber ID, for example, the IMSI for a GSM phone.